# Laravel 5, Vue JS. Как обратиться к объекту Vue не используя THIS

Tags: vue.js, laravel5

Вот часть кода из компонента Vue в проекте Laravel:

```
<script>
export default {

data() {
  return {
      item: {
          id: ''
      },
      api: ''
  }
},
methods: {
 getItem() {
    this.api = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/1?api_key=MY_API_KEY';

    $.getJSON(this.api)
        .done(function(received_data) {

          this.item = received_data;

        });
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

Цель - сохранить инфу, полученную через api в переменной item.
Однако THIS внутри getJSON не относится к объекту Vue.
Как обратиться к нему в таком случае?
То есть что использовать вместо this.item ?

Comment: можно заменить функцию на [стрелочную функцию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: и ещё почему вы пишите на таком модном фреймворке и используете такой не модный jQuery, и ещё возможно вы не хотели свой `api_key` всем показывать

Comment: Спасибо за наводку.
Модный Vue я только начал изучать и Laravel тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Я просто сделал ссылку на this таким образом:

```
showMovie(movieId)
        {
        this.api_with_movie_id = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/1?api_key=MY_API_KEY';

            var self = this;

            $.getJSON(this.api)
                    .done(function(received_data) {

                        self.item= received_data;

                        });
        }
```

Comment: но лучше бы заменили на стрелочную функцию :)